# HTML5 video loads slowly on FireFox, but it's pretty fast on Chrome

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, firefox, html5-video, http-proxy

I'm currently implementing a proxy for streaming video from another site from the company, transparently handling the authentication under the hood.

The whole authentication, partial content, and streaming part seems to work okay so far, except for some small detail: it works pretty fast on Chrome and Edge, but loads very slowly on FireFox. Moreover, this slowness on FireFox only happens if you play the video from the beginning; if you skip forth a few seconds, it plays normally from that point on. Also, weirdly enough, if support partial content is removed, the video loads okay on FireFox but, of course, skipping ahead becomes impossible.

One thing that I have noticed so far is that FireFox seems to first make a request without the 'range' header, and then it keeps making multiple requests with the 'range' header. Chrome on the other hand, makes only one request without 'range'; it will only add 'range' to the header if you try to skip ahead.

Also, FireFox seems to be requesting the same range multiple times when you play the video from the start.

Does anyone know why does FireFox behave this way, and what could I do to either change its behavior or provide what it needs?

```
'use strict'

const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const request = require('request');
const setCookie = require('set-cookie-parser');
const _ = require('lodash');

const logger = require('./log').normal;


const CAMINHO_BASE = 'http://placewherethevideosaretakenfrom/';

let videoEstaAutenticado = false;

router.get('/video/*', (req, res) => {

    let caminho = req.params[0];
    logger.info('Video no caminho ' + caminho, {range: req.headers.range});

    let caminhoCompleto = CAMINHO_BASE + caminho.split('/').map(encodeURIComponent).join('/');
    logger.info('Caminho completo ' + caminhoCompleto);

    request.debug = true; // FIXME: DEBUG

    const headersOriginais = req.headers;
    logger.info('Headers originais', {headersOriginais});

    function proxyVideo() {
        logger.info('Obtendo pedaço do vídeo.', req.headers);

        let headers = _.chain(req.headers)
            .pick(req.headers, 'accept', 'accept-encoding', 'connection', 'range', 'user-agent')
            .value();

        request(caminhoCompleto, {
            headers: headers,
            jar: true
        })
        .pipe(res);
    }

    if (videoEstaAutenticado) {
        proxyVideo();
    } else {
        console.info('Autenticando vídeo', {caminho});

        request.get(caminhoCompleto, {
            auth: {
                user: process.env.UNIVERSIDADE_USER,
                pass: process.env.UNIVERSIDADE_PASS
            },
            jar: true
        })
        .on('response', response => {
            videoEstaAutenticado = true;
            proxyVideo();
        });
    }

});

module.exports = router;
```

Some additional info: I have also experimented with serving the video statically via Apache; it works if accessing locally, but if I use ngrok (https://ngrok.com/) to be access it externally, exactly the same bug happens; it looks like FF has some problem with proxies/tunneling, or something like that.

The video is in mp4 format and the content-type is `video/mp4`.

Here go a few sample request/response headers.

```
Request URL: http://9e1f9fc2.ngrok.io/teste-temp/teste_1_digitacao.mp4
Status code: 200 OK

Response headers (263 B)    
Accept-Ranges   
bytes
Content-Length  
23182123
Content-Type    
video/mp4
Date    
Tue, 12 Dec 2017 11:26:04 GMT
ETag    
"161bb2b-55fbc97ec7340"
Last-Modified   
Thu, 07 Dec 2017 09:21:30 GMT
Server  
Apache/2.4.29 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2l PHP/5.6.32
Request headers (421 B) 
Accept  
text/html,application/xhtml+xm…plication/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding 
gzip, deflate
Accept-Language 
pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Connection  
keep-alive
Cookie  
_ga=GA1.2.1214318081.1511440374
Host    
9e1f9fc2.ngrok.io
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests   
1
User-Agent  
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; …) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0


===

Request URL: http://9e1f9fc2.ngrok.io/teste-temp/teste_1_digitacao.mp4
Status code: 206 Partial Content

Response headers (324 B)    
Accept-Ranges   
bytes
Content-Length  
20003627
Content-Range   
bytes 3178496-23182122/23182123
Content-Type    
video/mp4
Date    
Tue, 12 Dec 2017 11:26:08 GMT
ETag    
"161bb2b-55fbc97ec7340"
Last-Modified   
Thu, 07 Dec 2017 09:21:30 GMT
Server  
Apache/2.4.29 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2l PHP/5.6.32
Request headers (467 B) 
Accept  
video/webm,video/ogg,video/*;q…q=0.7,audio/*;q=0.6,*/*;q=0.5
Accept-Language 
pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Connection  
keep-alive
Cookie  
_ga=GA1.2.1214318081.1511440374
Host    
9e1f9fc2.ngrok.io
Range   
bytes=3178496-
Referer 
http://9e1f9fc2.ngrok.io/teste-temp/teste_1_digitacao.mp4
User-Agent  
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; …) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0

===

Request URL: http://9e1f9fc2.ngrok.io/teste-temp/teste_1_digitacao.mp4
Status code: 206 Partial Content

Response headers (324 B)    
Accept-Ranges   
bytes
Content-Length  
20003627
Content-Range   
bytes 3178496-23182122/23182123
Content-Type    
video/mp4
Date    
Tue, 12 Dec 2017 11:26:09 GMT
ETag    
"161bb2b-55fbc97ec7340"
Last-Modified   
Thu, 07 Dec 2017 09:21:30 GMT
Server  
Apache/2.4.29 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2l PHP/5.6.32
Request headers (467 B) 
Accept  
video/webm,video/ogg,video/*;q…q=0.7,audio/*;q=0.6,*/*;q=0.5
Accept-Language 
pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Connection  
keep-alive
Cookie  
_ga=GA1.2.1214318081.1511440374
Host    
9e1f9fc2.ngrok.io
Range   
bytes=3178496-
Referer 
http://9e1f9fc2.ngrok.io/teste-temp/teste_1_digitacao.mp4
User-Agent  
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; …) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0
```

Comment: Is your node app beign accessed directly or do you serve it thru a reverse proxy? Also, are the videos taged properly? What is the video format?

Comment: What is the content-type of the response? Also could you post some sample request/response headers for FF? Also does the Content-Length header match the file size in bytes?

Comment: The video is in mp4 format, and the content-type is `video/mp4`.

Comment: Do your video have proper timecode information/tagging? I had a similar issue and had to process the videos with FFMpeg to get it fixed

Comment: Supposing it would be a tagging problem, why would it work correcty when communicating directly to the server, and behave strangely when staying behind a proxy? Shouldn't the streamed data be the same in both cases?

Comment: The video has been tested both with a straight proxy (the app itself) and with a reverse proxy (ngrok, just to see what happens); in both cases, the behavior is the same.

Comment: this problem + many other slimier ones known from time to time in Firefox itself , the reason is firefox use (**`OpenH264 decoder`**)  as a modern plugin to run mp4/videos , the only solution i know to improve your HTML5 playback-Video performance is by creating a note inside pop-up window tell ur users to **Disable** (**`OpenH264 decoder`**) when they are on firefox . by going to **`about:config`** . and when that decoder disabled , the environment will run a native one more smoothly instead .